# .Net text generator

Tags: .net, text

Does anyone knows of a text generator like [this one](http://paggard.com/projects/txt.generator/), written in .Net ?
Open source would be nice, but it's not really important if it is free or not, as in speech or as in beer.
Basically, what I need is to reproduce a complex html table (a transaction summary) to ship it through email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[StringTemplate Template Engine](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)** may suit your needs. It is free (beer and speech included). There is a .NET port (check the *Downloads* section).

Answer (score 2):

There is the built in [Text Template Transformation Toolkit (T4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx):

> In Visual Studio, a T4 text template is a mixture of text blocks and control logic that can generate a text file. The control logic is written as fragments of program code in Visual C# or Visual Basic. The generated file can be text of any kind, such as a Web page, or a resource file, or program source code in any language.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure it can reach my goal. I've updated my question. Thanks.